# Subset a dataframe between 2 dates

Tags: r, date, subset

I am working with daily returns from a Brazilian Index (IBOV) since 1993, I am trying to figure out the best way to subset for periods between 2 dates.

The data frame (`IBOV_RET`) is as follows :

```
head(IBOV_RET)
        DATE    1D_RETURN
1 1993-04-28 -0.008163265
2 1993-04-29 -0.024691358
3 1993-04-30  0.016877637
4 1993-05-03  0.000000000
5 1993-05-04  0.033195021
6 1993-05-05 -0.012048193
...
```

I set 2 variables `DATE1` and `DATE2` as dates

```
DATE1 <- as.Date("2014-04-01")
DATE2 <- as.Date("2014-05-05")
```

I was able to create a new subset using this code:

```
TEST <- IBOV_RET[IBOV_RET$DATE >= DATE1 & IBOV_RET$DATE <= DATE2,]
```

It worked, but I was wondering if there is a better way to subset the data between 2 date, maybe using `subset`.

Comment: If you name your dataframe ``df``  and your dates ``t1`` and ``t2``, you can get something shorter like: ``df[df$Date %in% t1:t2, ]``. To clarify,  ``t1:t2`` works with dates, so you don't need to have inequalities.

Answer (score 24):

As already pointed out by @MrFlick, you dont get around the basic logic of subsetting. One way to make it easier for you to subset your specific data.frame would be to define a function that takes two inputs like `DATE1` and `DATE2` in your example and then returns the subset of `IBOV_RET` according to those subset parameters.

```
myfunc <- function(x,y){IBOV_RET[IBOV_RET$DATE >= x & IBOV_RET$DATE <= y,]}

DATE1 <- as.Date("1993-04-29")
DATE2 <- as.Date("1993-05-04")

Test <- myfunc(DATE1,DATE2)    

#> Test
#        DATE  X1D_RETURN
#2 1993-04-29 -0.02469136
#3 1993-04-30  0.01687764
#4 1993-05-03  0.00000000
#5 1993-05-04  0.03319502
```

You can also enter the specific dates directly into `myfunc`:

```
myfunc(as.Date("1993-04-29"),as.Date("1993-05-04")) #will produce the same result
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `subset()` function with the `&` operator:

```
subset(IBOV_RET, DATE1> XXXX-XX-XX & DATE2 < XXXX-XX-XX)
```

Updating for a more "tidyverse-oriented" approach:

```
IBOV_RET %>%
  filter(DATE1 > XXXX-XX-XX, DATE2 < XXXX-XX-XX) #comma same as &
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no real other way to extract date ranges. The logic is the same as extracting a range of numeric values as well, you just need to do the explicit Date conversion as you've done. You can make your subsetting shorter as you would with any other subsetting task with `subset` or `with`. You can break ranges into intervals with `cut` (there is a specific `cut.Date` overload). But base R does not have any way to specify Date literals so you cannot avoid the conversion. I can't imagine what other sort of syntax you may have had in mind.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
DATE1 <- as.Date("1993-04-29")
DATE2 <- as.Date("1993-05-04")

# creating a data range with the start and end date:
dates <- seq(DATE1, DATE2, by="days")

IBOV_RET <- subset(IBOV_RET, DATE %in% dates)
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe `lubridate` could help here;

```
daterange <- interval(DATE1, DATE2)
TEST <- IBOV_RET[which(Date %within% daterange),]
```

Answer (score 1):

I sort of love `dplyr` package
So if you

```
>library("dplyr")
```

and then, as you did:

```
>Date1<-as.Date("2014-04-01")  
>Date2<-as.Date("2014-05-05")
```

Finally

```
>test<-filter(IBOV_RET, filter(DATE>Date1 & DATE<Date2))
```

Comment: Calling `filter` twice like this doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use R's `between()` function after simply converting the strings to dates:

```
df %>%
    filter(between(date_column, as.Date("string-date-lower-bound"), as.Date("string-date-upper-bound")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Test = IBOV_RET[IBOV_RET$Date => "2014-04-01" | IBOV_RET$Date <= "1993-05-04"]
```

Here I am using "or" function | where data should be greater than particular data or data should be less than or equal to this date.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The comment by @Yunnosch is _always_ useful to keep in mind, but _especially_ here where there's already a couple of answers that have been validated by the community. How does your answer differ from the existing answers? In what conditions might it be preferred?

Comment: I am sorry for late reply.