# How to select some rows with specific date from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have a large dataset and I want to pick out some of the rows particularly, I am wondering if anyone could help me with this? Thank you so much for your help!!

For example, if I just want pick out rows that are from 2/1/2008-5/1/2008 plus 9/1/2008-11/1/2008, how can I do that?
Thank you very much!!

Can anyone please help?

```
date    mpressure   mxtemp
2008-01-01  1025.3  15.7
2008-01-02  1025.6  16.0    <   
2008-01-03  1023.6  18.1    <
2008-01-04  1021.8  18.4    <
2008-01-05  1020.1  20.9    <
2008-01-06  1019.7  20.7
2008-01-07  1018.4  24.0
2008-01-08  1016.7  23.7
2008-01-09  1015.3  24.5    <
2008-01-10  1014.3  21.8    <
2008-01-11  1012.9  23.4    <
```

And then I will get something like this?

```
date    mpressure   mxtemp
2008-01-02  1025.6  16.0    <   
2008-01-03  1023.6  18.1    <
2008-01-04  1021.8  18.4    <
2008-01-05  1020.1  20.9    <
2008-01-09  1015.3  24.5    <
2008-01-10  1014.3  21.8    <
2008-01-11  1012.9  23.4    <
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subset a dataframe between 2 dates in R (Better Way)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622338/subset-a-dataframe-between-2-dates-in-r-better-way)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert your date column to `Date`-type:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

Then subset according to your specifications:

```
with(df, df[(date >= "2008-01-02" & date <= "2008-01-05") | 
                                 (date >= "2008-01-09" & date <= "2008-01-11"), ])
#         date mpressure mxtemp
#2  2008-01-02    1025.6   16.0
#3  2008-01-03    1023.6   18.1
#4  2008-01-04    1021.8   18.4
#5  2008-01-05    1020.1   20.9
#9  2008-01-09    1015.3   24.5
#10 2008-01-10    1014.3   21.8
#11 2008-01-11    1012.9   23.4
```