# Remove rows after a certain date based on a condition in R

Tags: r, date, conditional-statements

There are similar questions I've seen, but none of them apply it to specific rows of a data.table or data.frame, rather they apply it to the whole matrix.
[Subset a dataframe between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622338/subset-a-dataframe-between-2-dates-in-r-better-way)
[How to select some rows with specific date from a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024510/how-to-select-some-rows-with-specific-date-from-a-data-frame-in-r)

I have a dataset with patients who were diagnosed with OA and those who were not:

```
 dt <- data.table(ID = seq(1,10,1), OA = c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0), 
             oa.date = as.Date(c("01/01/2006", "01/01/2001", "01/01/2001", "02/03/2005","01/01/2001","01/01/2001","01/01/2001","05/06/2010", "01/01/2011", "01/01/2001"), "%d/%m/%Y"),
             stop.date = as.Date(c("01/01/2006", "31/12/2007", "31/12/2008", "02/03/2005", "31/12/2011", "31/12/2011", "31/12/2011", "05/06/2010", "01/01/2011", "31/12/2011"), "%d/%m/%Y"))
dt$oa.date[dt$OA==0] <- NA

> dt
    ID OA    oa.date  stop.date
 1:  1  1 2006-01-01 2006-01-01
 2:  2  0       <NA> 2007-12-31
 3:  3  0       <NA> 2008-12-31
 4:  4  1 2005-03-02 2005-03-02
 5:  5  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
 6:  6  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
 7:  7  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
 8:  8  1 2010-06-05 2010-06-05
 9:  9  1 2011-01-01 2011-01-01
10: 10  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
```

What I want to do is delete those who were diagnosed with OA (`OA==1`) before `start`:

```
start <- as.Date("01/01/2009", "%d/%m/%Y")
```

So I want my final data to be:

```
> dt
     ID OA    oa.date  stop.date
 1:  2  0       <NA> 2009-12-31
 2:  3  0       <NA> 2008-12-31
 3:  5  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
 4:  6  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
 5:  7  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
 6:  8  1 2010-06-05 2010-06-05
 7:  9  1 2011-01-01 2011-01-01
 8: 10  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
```

My  tries are:

```
  dt[dt$OA==1] <- dt[!(oa.date < start)]
```

I've also tried a loop but to no effect.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be straightforward:

```
> dt[!(OA & oa.date < start)]
#   ID OA    oa.date  stop.date
#1:  2  0       <NA> 2007-12-31
#2:  3  0       <NA> 2008-12-31
#3:  5  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
#4:  6  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
#5:  7  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
#6:  8  1 2010-06-05 2010-06-05
#7:  9  1 2011-01-01 2011-01-01
#8: 10  0       <NA> 2011-12-31
```

The `OA` column is binary (1/0) which is coerced to logical (TRUE/FALSE) in the i-expression.

Comment: That is  simple, I don't know why that didn't occur to me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
dt=dt[dt$OA==0|(dt$OA==1&!(dt$oa.date < start)),]
```