# Get times on a certain date form list in R

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a list of times parced with anytime like so:

```
library(anytime)
time <- anytime(ACC$Time)
```

The content of that parced list is like this:

```
[1] "2018-12-03 12:36:10 CET"
[2] "2018-12-03 12:36:10 CET"
[3] "2018-12-03 12:36:10 CET"
[4] "2018-12-03 12:36:10 CET"
```

There are a few hundered thousand entries in and i would like to retrieve all entries of a certain day in my case "2018-12-03". So that i can extract the time and plot that time on graph as an X-axis

Comment: If you're using [`ggplot2` to plot your dates](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html), you don't need to change anything. Just specify the correct breaks and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to subset `time` by the date `"2018-12-03"`, maybe you can use the following code, i.e.,

```
time[grepl("2018-12-03",time)]
```

or

```
grep("2018-12-03",time,value = T)
```

or

```
subset(time, as.Date(time)=="2018-12-03")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#example data
time <- c("2018-12-01 12:36:10 CET", "2018-12-02 12:36:10 CET", 
       "2018-12-03 12:36:10 CET", "2018-12-04 12:36:10 CET")

#turning date time into date
date <- as.Date(time)

#subset data within a data frame
df <- as.data.frame(date)
subset <-  with(df, df[(date == "2018-12-03"),])
```

The result gives you a subset of only the specific day(s) you want

Based off of this answer:
[How to select some rows with specific date from a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024510/how-to-select-some-rows-with-specific-date-from-a-data-frame-in-r)