# R - How to subset a table between two specific dates?

Tags: r

I have hourly data values of eight years, and I would like to subset all the values within an specific year. For example a data set for 2007, another for 2008 and so on. At the moment I have many problems with the date format, because when I specific a time period, I get another date period.

Here is my table: [LValley](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tya5xae4f9l4xu5/LValley.txt?dl=0), and that is what I have tried:

```
LValley <- read.table("C:/LValley.txt", header=TRUE, dec = ",", sep="\t")

year2007 <- subset(LValley, date > as.Date("01.01.2007 01:00", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M") & date < as.Date("01.02.2008 01:00", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))
```

but it returns me another date period, and I would like exactly all the data from 2007.

I have used also the function of this example, and I have the same results # [Subset a dataframe between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622338/subset-a-dataframe-between-2-dates-in-r-better-way)

```
mydatefunc <- function(x,y){LValley[LValley$date >= x & LValley$date <= y,]}

DATE1 <- as.Date("01.01.2007 01:00", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
DATE2 <- as.Date("01.01.2008 00:00", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")

Test2007 <- mydatefunc(DATE1,DATE2)
```

I will appreciate very much you help,

Kind regards,
Darwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `date` column in the file to `date` class. For example:

```
 LValley <- read.table("LValley.txt", header=TRUE,dec=",", sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  date1 <- as.Date(LValley$date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
  Test2007 <- subset(LValley, date1>=DATE1 & date1 <=DATE2)
  dim(Test2007)
   #[1] 6249    4
```

Comment: Sticking `LValley` in the function is a bad idea, better to pass it in as a parameter. Or use `subset`, or use `filter` from `dplyr`.