# R: How to filter/subset a sequence of dates

Tags: r, filter, subset, dplyr

I have this data: (complete for December)

```
      date     sessions
1   2014-12-01  1932
2   2014-12-02  1828
3   2014-12-03  2349
4   2014-12-04  8192
5   2014-12-05  3188
6   2014-12-06  3277
```

And a need to subset/filter this, for example from "2014-12-05" to "2014-12-25"

I know that you can create a sequence with the operator ":".

Example: b <- c(1:5)

But How to filter a sequence? I tried this

```
NewDate <- filter(Dates, date("2014-12-05":"2014-12-12"))
```

But says:

> Error: unexpected symbol in: "NewDate <- filter(Dates,
> date("2014-12-05":"2014-12-12") NewDate"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subset a dataframe between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622338/subset-a-dataframe-between-2-dates)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you could use `subset`

Generating your sample data:

```
temp<-
read.table(text="date     sessions
2014-12-01  1932
2014-12-02  1828
2014-12-03  2349
2014-12-04  8192
2014-12-05  3188
2014-12-06  3277", header=T)
```

Making sure it's in date format:

```
temp$date <- as.Date(temp$date, format= "%Y-%m-%d")

temp



 #        date sessions
 # 1 2014-12-01     1932
 # 2 2014-12-02     1828
 # 3 2014-12-03     2349
 # 4 2014-12-04     8192
 # 5 2014-12-05     3188
 # 6 2014-12-06     3277
```

Using `subset` :

```
subset(temp, date> "2014-12-03" & date < "2014-12-05")
```

which gives:

```
  #        date sessions
  # 4 2014-12-04     8192
```

you could also use `[]`:

```
temp[(temp$date> "2014-12-03" & temp$date < "2014-12-05"),]
```

Comment: This was so simple, thanks! i think i'm so tired i'm just making things harder in my head than they really are...

Answer (score 30):

If you want to use `dplyr`, you can try something like this.

```
mydf <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16405, 16406, 16407, 16408, 
16409, 16410), class = "Date"), sessions = c(1932L, 1828L, 2349L, 
8192L, 3188L, 3277L)), .Names = c("date", "sessions"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")

# Create date object
mydf$date <- as.Date(mydf$date) 

filter(mydf, between(date, as.Date("2014-12-02"), as.Date("2014-12-05")))

#If you avoid using `between()`, the code is simpler.

filter(mydf, date >= "2014-12-02", date <= "2014-12-05")
filter(mydf, date >= "2014-12-02" & date <= "2014-12-05")

#        date sessions
#1 2014-12-02     1828
#2 2014-12-03     2349
#3 2014-12-04     8192
#4 2014-12-05     3188
```

Comment: I thought the logical condition would be `&`, but looks like the `,` works.  It is something new for me. Thanks.

Comment: @akrun It seems that both are fine here, doesn't it? I saw both versions in Hadley's dplyr tutorial pdf from UseR! 2014. I will post both versions. I am a bit puzzled by the behaviour of `between`. I wonder why one needs to use `as.Date` again.

Comment: Same reason `seq.Date(as.Date(x1),as.Date(x2),by="years")` requires it - you need to work on a `Date` object so the data matches.

Comment: @thelatemail That example cleared up my mind. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @akrun Pleasure as always. It seems that `between` in `data.table` saves some typing.

Answer (score 12):

An option using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[date %between% c('2014-12-02', '2014-12-05')]
 #         date sessions
 #1: 2014-12-02     1828
 #2: 2014-12-03     2349
 #3: 2014-12-04     8192
 #4: 2014-12-05     3188
```

This should work even if the "date" is "character" column

```
 df$date <- as.character(df$date)
 setDT(df)[date %between% c('2014-12-02', '2014-12-05')]
 #       date sessions
 #1: 2014-12-02     1828
 #2: 2014-12-03     2349
 #3: 2014-12-04     8192
 #4: 2014-12-05     3188
```

In case if we wanted to subset exclusive of the range

```
  setDT(df)[between(date, '2014-12-02', '2014-12-05', incbounds=FALSE)]
  #         date sessions
  #1:  2014-12-03     2349
  #2:  2014-12-04     8192
```

#### data

```
 df <-  structure(list(date = structure(c(16405, 16406, 16407, 16408, 
 16409, 16410), class = "Date"), sessions = c(1932L, 1828L, 2349L, 
 8192L, 3188L, 3277L)), .Names = c("date", "sessions"), row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I've been looking for the fastest date filtering option to use inside `ggplot::geom_xxxx(data=DT[])`. Quick research suggests this would be the fastest option: does it matter in terms of performance to use %between% or between()? Is it using as.Date() in the internals?
What I'm doing:
'ggplot(DT, aes(date, y_var)) +
  geom_step() +
  geom_step(data = DT[,DATE %in% ymd("2017-02-01"):ymd("2017-10-31"),] , aes(date, yvar), col='black', size=1.6 )'

This is just to highlight the current (2017) year line: "black" and size bigger.

Comment: @Dan If you are using the `between` from `data.table` i.e. `between(x, lower, upper, incbounds=TRUE)#
x %between% y`

Comment: Does %between% transform the date character to a true date?
What's the difference between using data.table's %between% and using lubridate's %within%?

Answer (score 0):

With `lubridate`,

```
mydates <- interval(start = "2014-12-05", end = "2014-12-25")
NewDate <- Dates[which(date %within% mydates),]
```

Comment: You don't need `which`.

Comment: Disagree. `Which` indexes the rows which fit the condition and returns a subset of those. Otherwise the subsetting index is a vector of TRUE/FALSE, but NA rows will be neither T nor F and thus return all-NA rows to the result.

Comment: You're right. Interesting. I thought subsetting would only return TRUEs instead of just not returning FALSEs (since NA is a logical too). Been using `dplyr` too much I guess. Using it in `filter` doesn't return the NA. Thanks.