# Filter by specific range of dates in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

```
ID    Date     Score
17   4/3/2020   13
18   6/2/2021   90
3    7/2/2019   15
4    8/1/2020   87
5    8/9/2020   78
20   6/7/2020   18
19   5/4/2020   55
17   5/29/2020  44
```

I want to only keep the rows that are from the date 4/1/2020 to 6/30/2020 so that the final df is:

```
   ID    Date     Score
    17   4/3/2020   13
    18   6/2/2021   90
    20   6/7/2020   18
    19   5/4/2020   55
    17   5/29/2020  44
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: How to filter/subset a sequence of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335715/r-how-to-filter-subset-a-sequence-of-dates)

Comment: In the expected output shown 6/2/2021 is not within the dates mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

With tidyverse and lubridate, try

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  data.frame(ID = c(17, 18, 3, 4, 5, 20, 19, 17), 
             Date = c("4/3/2020", "6/2/2021", "7/2/2019", "8/1/2020", "8/9/2020", "6/7/2020", "5/4/2020", "5/29/2020"), 
             Score = c(13, 90, 15, 87, 78, 18, 55, 44))

df %>% 
 mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>% 
 filter(Date > as.Date("2020-04-01"), 
        Date < as.Date("2020-06-30"))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID Date       Score
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1    17 2020-04-03    13
2    20 2020-06-07    18
3    19 2020-05-04    55
4    17 2020-05-29    44
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end convert the Date to yearqtr (a class that represents year and quarter and then extract the indicated one).

```
library(zoo)
subset(dat, as.yearqtr(Date, "%m/%d/%Y") == "2020 Q2")
```

giving:

```
  ID      Date Score
1 17  4/3/2020    13
6 20  6/7/2020    18
7 19  5/4/2020    55
8 17 5/29/2020    44
```

This would also work as yearqtr uses the internal representation year + fraction where the fraction is 0, 0.25, 0.5 and 0.75 for the four quarters.

```
subset(dat, as.yearqtr(Date, "%m/%d/%Y") == 2020.25)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "ID    Date     Score
17   4/3/2020   13
18   6/2/2021   90
3    7/2/2019   15
4    8/1/2020   87
5    8/9/2020   78
20   6/7/2020   18
19   5/4/2020   55
17   5/29/2020  44"
dat <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your data in a data.frame or tibble called `df` then you can use the `lubridate` and `dplyr` packages to subset your data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  filter(mdy(`Date`) >= as.Date('2020-04-01') & mdy(`Date`) <= as.Date('2020-06-30'))
```