# Filtering dates in dplyr

Tags: r, date, filter, dplyr, between

My tbl_df:

```
    > p2p_dt_SKILL_A%>%
    + select(Patch,Date,Prod_DL)%>%
    + head()
      Patch       Date Prod_DL
    1  P1 2015-09-04    3.43
    2 P11 2015-09-11    3.49
    3 P12 2015-09-18    3.45
...
    4 P13 2015-12-06    3.57
    5 P14 2015-12-13    3.43
    6 P15 2015-12-20    3.47
```

I want to select all `rows` based on the date for example if `Date` is greater than `2015-09-04` and less than `2015-09-18`

The result should be:

```
      Patch       Date          Prod_DL
      P1        2015-09-04    3.43
      P11       2015-09-11    3.49
```

I tried the following but it returns empty empty vector.

```
p2p_dt_SKILL_A%>%
                select(Patch,Date,Prod_DL)%>%
                filter(Date > "2015-09-04" & Date <"2015-09-18")
```

Just returns:

```
> p2p_dt_SKILL_A%>%
+                 select(Patch,Date,Prod_DL)%>%
+                 filter(Date > 2015-09-12 & Date <2015-09-18)
Source: local data table [0 x 3]

Variables not shown: Patch (fctr), Date (date), Prod_DL (dbl)
```

Also tried with quotes.

And using `lubridate`

```
p2p_dt_SKILL_A%>%
                select(Patch,Date,Prod_DL)%>%
                #filter(Date > 2015-09-12 & Date <2015-09-18)%>%
                filter(Patch %in% c("BVG1"),month(p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date) == 9)%>%
                arrange(Date)
```

But this gives me whole September data.

Is there a more efficient way like using the `between` operator from `dplyr` on `Date` types variables?

Comment: Can you add str(p2p_dt_SKILL_A) in your question. I want to see if Date is a `date` object or something else

Comment: @PLapointe its already there in the return part. `Variables not shown: Patch (fctr), Date (date), Prod_DL (dbl)` ... Its a Date type

Comment: The dates are not quoted (") in that part of your code. Using your code just above that, it works. Look at my answer below.

Comment: @PLapointe tried with both quotes and unquotes...doesn't work... my dataframe is of type `tbl_df`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subset a dataframe between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622338/subset-a-dataframe-between-2-dates)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If Date is properly formatted as a `date`, your first try works:

```
p2p_dt_SKILL_A <-read.table(text="Patch,Date,Prod_DL
P1,9/4/2015,3.43
P11,9/11/2015,3.49
P12,9/18/2015,3.45
P13,12/6/2015,3.57
P14,12/13/2015,3.43
P15,12/20/2015,3.47
",sep=",",stringsAsFactors =FALSE, header=TRUE)

p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date <-as.Date(p2p_dt_SKILL_A$Date,"%m/%d/%Y")

p2p_dt_SKILL_A%>%
                select(Patch,Date,Prod_DL)%>%
                filter(Date > "2015-09-04" & Date <"2015-09-18")
  Patch       Date Prod_DL
1 P11 2015-09-11    3.49
```

---

---

Still works if data is of type `tbl_df`.

```
p2p_dt_SKILL_A <-tbl_df(p2p_dt_SKILL_A)

p2p_dt_SKILL_A%>%
                select(Patch,Date,Prod_DL)%>%
                filter(Date > "2015-09-04" & Date <"2015-09-18")
Source: local data frame [1 x 3]

  Patch       Date Prod_DL
  (chr)     (date)   (dbl)
1 P11 2015-09-11    3.49
```

Answer (score 19):

Another more verbose option would be to use the function `between`, *a shortcut for x >= left & x <= right*. We need to change the days to account for the `=` sign, and to use `as.Date` (explanation [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1639)).

```
p2p_dt_SKILL_A%>%
                select(Patch,Date,Prod_DL)%>%
                filter(between(Date, as.Date("2015-09-05"),as.Date("2015-09-17")))
```