# Find if a date in a date vector falls between two dates

Tags: r, vector

I have two date vectors, a and b. Vector a has two dates defining a date span. Vector b could have many elements, but I want to know which (if any) element of b falls inside the date span of a. For example,

```
 a <- c(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-02-01"))
 b <- c(as.Date("2011-11-09"), as.Date("2012-01-15"), as.Date("2012-5-15"))
```

Vectors a and b could be zoo/xts objects with numerical values assigned to the dates, or not as required to help with a solution.

The desired answer would be b[2], 2012-01-15. Obviously one can use loops, but there must be a vector solution to this. Help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622338/subset-a-dataframe-between-2-dates

Answer (score 3):

It can be easily done with `lubridate` e.g.:

```
library(lubridate)
```

We first define an interval `a`:

```
a <- as.interval(a)
```

Then using the `%within%` function we assess if any element of `b` falls within `a`:

```
b[b %within% a]

[1] "2012-01-15"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `between`from `dplyr`. As the name suggests `between` gives those values which fall in between two values (here `a[1]` and `a[2]`).

```
library(dplyr)
b[between(b, a[1], a[2])]

#[1] "2012-01-15"
```

Or if we are interested in base R solution, the simplest would be

```
b[b > a[1] & b < a[2]]

#[1] "2012-01-15"
```