# Extract the months that fall in a lubridate interval

Tags: r, lubridate

Given a lubridate interval, for example:

```
start <- "2016-09-24"
finish <- "2016-11-02"
my_interval <- lubridate::interval(start, finish)
my_interval

> my_interval
[1] 2016-09-24 UTC--2016-11-02 UTC
```

I would like to be able to extract the months that fall into this interval, in this case:

```
[1] "Sep" "Oct" "Nov"
```

So far, my best attempt at this is really clunky:

```
my_months <- list(
  "Aug" = interval("2016-08-01", "2016-08-31"), 
  "Sep" = interval("2016-09-01", "2016-09-30"), 
  "Oct" = interval("2016-10-01", "2016-10-31"), 
  "Nov" = interval("2016-11-01", "2016-11-30"), 
  "Dec" = interval("2016-12-01", "2016-12-31")
)

extract_months <- function(x, months) {
  out <- vector(mode = "character")

  for (i in seq_along(months)) {
    in_month <- int_overlaps(x, months[[i]])
    if (in_month) {
      out[i] <- names(months)[i]
    }
    out <- out[!is.na(out)]
  }
  out
}

extract_months(x = my_interval, months = my_months)

> extract_months(x = my_interval, months = my_months)
[1] "Sep" "Oct" "Nov"
```

over many years this quickly becomes unwieldy. I'm hoping somebody has a better solution.

I fail to see how this question is a duplicate of [Subset a dataframe between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898837/extract-the-months-that-fall-in-a-lubridate-interval?noredirect=1#comment80745734_46898837)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subset a dataframe between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622338/subset-a-dataframe-between-2-dates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually very simple!

```
library(lubridate)
month.abb[month(start):month(finish)]
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with @Kim's solution is, that it won't work anymore if an interval spans over 1 year:

```
library(lubridate)
# works:
month.abb[month("2016-09-24"):month("2016-11-02")]
[1] "Sep" "Oct" "Nov"
# wrong (should be Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan):
month.abb[month("2016-09-24"):month("2017-01-02")]
[1] "Sep" "Aug" "Jul" "Jun" "May" "Apr" "Mar" "Feb" "Jan"
```

One solution could be:

```
# correct:
month.abb[unique(month(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2016-09-24"), to = as.Date("2017-01-02"), by = "day")))]
[1] "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec" "Jan"
```

Comment: Good you show the accepted solution is not robust. For speed, you can change `by = "day"` by e.g. `by="25 days"`. You won't miss a unique month

Answer (score 0):

One step further might include the year:

```
library(lubridate)

# the next 12 months starting on the first of next month
my_interval = interval(ceiling_date(Sys.Date(),unit = "month"),
ceiling_date(Sys.Date(),unit = "month") + years(1) - days(1))

year_month_vec <- paste0(year(seq.Date(from = date(int_start(my_interval)),to = date(int_end(my_interval)),by = "month")),"-",
  month.abb[month(seq.Date(from = date(int_start(my_interval)),to = date(int_end(my_interval)),by = "month"))])
```