# unexpected error when subsetting data.frame by range of date in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I got projection data in data.frame (resulted by projecting all german weather stations data to German shapefile). However, in my first step, I want to extract out all rows whose `begin date` and `end date` attributes within `01.01.1981 ~ 31.12.2014`. So I did take subset on original merged data.frame, but don't know why the operation was failed. I shared original data in `csv` format on fly ([data is here](http://jmp.sh/Kqr7LaW)). Basically, I am gonna keep all instances whose date interval between `01.01.1981 ~ 31.12.2014` (I need to analyze recent 35 years weather data of Germany ). I am pretty sure my code can work with my data, but still failed at the end. Any quick solution? How can I make this happen in R? Is `dplyr`, `data.table` can help for this? Any more thoughts? Thanks

Here is the what data look like (original data source is placed on the fly):

```
 Stationsname Stations_ID ID__Index Station.Identification   Width Length Station_Height River_Basin Federal_state
1         Aach           1        KL                  02783 47.8410 8.8490            478          NA            BW
2         Aach           1        RR                  70191 47.8410 8.8490            478          NA            BW
3   Aach/Hegau       10771        PE                  10771 47.8500 8.8500            480          NA            BW
4       Aachen           3        EB                  02205 50.7827 6.0941            202      803100            NW
5       Aachen           3        FF                  02205 50.7827 6.0941            202      803100            NW
6       Aachen           3        KL                  02205 50.7827 6.0941            202      803100            NW
       Begin        End ID_0 ISO  NAME_0 ID_1               NAME_1 ID_2                 NAME_2   HASC_2 CCN_2 CCA_2
1 01.01.1937 30.06.1986   86 DEU Germany    1 Baden-WÃƒÂ¼rttemberg   22               Konstanz DE.BW.KN     0  8335
2 01.01.1912 30.06.1986   86 DEU Germany    1 Baden-WÃƒÂ¼rttemberg   22               Konstanz DE.BW.KN     0  8335
3                         86 DEU Germany    1 Baden-WÃƒÂ¼rttemberg   22               Konstanz DE.BW.KN     0  8335
4 01.01.1951 31.03.2011   86 DEU Germany   10  Nordrhein-Westfalen  290 StÃƒÂ¤dteregion Aachen DE.NW.AC     0  5334
5 01.01.1937 31.03.2011   86 DEU Germany   10  Nordrhein-Westfalen  290 StÃƒÂ¤dteregion Aachen DE.NW.AC     0  5334
6 01.01.1891 31.03.2011   86 DEU Germany   10  Nordrhein-Westfalen  290 StÃƒÂ¤dteregion Aachen DE.NW.AC     0  5334
     TYPE_2 ENGTYPE_2 NL_NAME_2 VARNAME_2
1 Landkreis  District        NA          
2 Landkreis  District        NA          
3 Landkreis  District        NA          
4     Kreis  District        NA          
5     Kreis  District        NA          
6     Kreis  District        NA
```

I read the experimental dataset down below:

```
joinedData <- read.csv(file = "~/joinedLayer_attrTabl.csv",sep = "," ,header = TRUE)
head(as.data.frame(joinedData)); tail(as.data.frame(joinedData))
```

This is my initial tryout:

```
dateInterval <- function(x,y){joinedData[joinedData$Begin >= x 
                                         & joinedData$End <= y,]}
DATE1 <- as.Date("01-01-1981")
DATE2 <- as.Date("31-12-2014")
res <- dateInterval(DATE1,DATE2)
```

Here is the error that raised by Rstudio:

```
> dateInterval <- function(x,y){joinedData[joinedData$Begin > x & joinedData$End < y, ]}
> 
> DATE1 <- as.Date("01-01-1981")
> DATE2 <- as.Date("31-12-2014")
> res <- dateInterval(DATE1,DATE2)
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.frame`(joinedData, joinedData$Begin > x & joinedData$End <  :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.Date") for ">"
2: In `[.data.frame`(joinedData, joinedData$Begin > x & joinedData$End <  :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.Date") for "<"
```

I also tried this down below:

```
joinedData[joinedData$Begin & joinedData$End %between% c("01.01.1981", "31.12.2014"),]
```

still, I didn't get my expected result. Why did this error happen to me? Any idea?

**Output**:

I am gonna select all rows whose begin and end data falls within my specified date interval. Any way to fix the problem? How can I make this happen?

Comment: right now this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622338/subset-a-dataframe-between-2-dates.  Can you edit your question - maybe include the error you're getting - to differentiate it from that one?

Comment: @SamFirke Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I attached the error and my session info. Any quick solution for that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see couple of problem in OP's code.

**Prob#1**: The default format expected by `as.Date` is `"%Y-%m-%d" or "%Y/%m/%d"`. But the formats of the characters (`Begin`, `End` columns) used in code is `%d.%m.%Y` or `%s-%m-%Y`. Hence default `format` in function `as.Date()` will not work. The `format` argument should specifically provided to `as.Date()` function.

The correct code to create `DATE1` and `DATE2` should be:

```
DATE1 <- as.Date("01-01-1981", format = "%d-%m-%Y")
DATE2 <- as.Date("31-12-2014", , format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

**Prob#2:** The `Begin` and `End` columns of dataframe should be changed to `as.Date` format as well before attempting filter operations.

The format of those 2 columns can be changed as:

```
joinedData$Begin = as.Date(joinedData$Begin, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
joinedData$End= as.Date(joinedData$End, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

Now, the OP'2 initial approach should work.

**Note:** Personally I prefer using `as.POSIXlt` over `as.Date`