# How do I subset a specific date range in R?

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to get a subset of the dataframe that has a range of dates and a format of '2016-10-01 00:00'.

Below is my current code, but it produces an error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In which(classsched$DateTime >= x & classsched$DateTime <= y) :
Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.Date") for ">="
2: In which(classsched$DateTime >= x & classsched$DateTime <= y) :
Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.Date") for "<="
```

My code:

```
dateFunction <- function(x,y){
  classsched[which(classsched$DateTime >= x & classsched$DateTime <=y)]
}

date1 = as.Date('2016-10-01 00:00', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
date2 = as.Date('2017-10-31 23:59', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

test <- dateFunction(date1, date2)
```

My dataset:

```
 DateTime            Course    Professor-in-Time
2016-01-01 11:10    CS        Morgan
2016-10-03 12:16    Eng       Andrew
2017-05-05 13:17    Poetry    Jen
2018-04-15 14:11    Reading   Eugene
2018-05-20 15:21    Math      Matt

DateTime <- as.Date(c('2016-01-01 11:10','2016-10-03 12:16','2017-05-05
13:17', '2018-04-15 14:11', '2018-05-20 15:21'))
Course <- c('CS','Eng','Poetry', 'Reading', 'Math')
Professor-in-Time <- c('Morgan', 'Andrew', 'Jen', 'Eugene', 'Matt')
classsched <- dataframe(DateTime, Course, Professor-in-Time)
```

So the output should be:

```
 DateTime            Course    Professor-in-Time
2016-10-03 12:16    Eng       Andrew
2017-05-05 13:17    Poetry    Jen
```

I based my code originally from Stack Overflow question *[Subset a dataframe between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622338/subset-a-dataframe-between-2-dates?fbclid=IwAR0pBjrhJmufboXXtPm4awSUHQbFbLffmcd7pj-56vZ7aNvoCL9jZsh4C0g)*.

Comment: Do you care about the time components?  I don't think R's base date type knows about time?

Comment: no, I just need the date component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

First of all, you should provide some data that is easier to reproduce [e.g use dput](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/dput). Secondly, your date formats are mixed up.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(DateTime = dmy_hm("01/1/2016 11:10", "03/10/2016 12:16", "05/05/2017 13:17", "15/04/2018 14:11", "20/05/2018 15:21"),
             Course = c("CS", "Eng", "Poetry", "Reading", "Maths"),
             Prof_in_time = c("Morgan", "Andrew", "Jen", "Eugene", "Matt"))
df #note typos in the date format in your data
```

Then you could do this:

```
start <- dmy_hm("01/1/2016 00:00") #note you had different formats
end <- dmy_hm("31/10/2016 23:59")

df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(DateTime >= start & DateTime <= end)
df2
```

This filters your dates. This might not match yours as I played around with the date formats.

Or you could do this instead:

```
df3 <- df %>% 
  filter(DateTime >= dmy_hm("01/1/2016 00:00") & DateTime <= dmy_hm("31/10/2016 23:59"))
df3
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I copied pasted from an excel file rather than a csv file so it messed up the formatting of the dates. I've edited the data now.

Comment: I tried on doing this: start<- classsched$DateTime('2016-10-01 00:00') but produces this error Error in classsched$DateTime("2016-10-01 00:00") : could not find function "classsched$DateTime"

Comment: In my example I have defined 'start' and 'end' outside of the data frame. They are just saved as values. They are then put in to the filter statement. I have now added to the answer, see the df3 example.